# Deploy Asp Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deploy

Fiz deploy de um site simples que ainda  está em desenvolvimento, o endereço é http://www.datussistemas.com.br, porém não sei como resolver o problema que acontece quanto tento acessar. Alguém já passou por esse problema?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error: 

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

  <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.
```

Comment: Que problema? O que aparece? Quais passos já fez? Qual o seu ambiente? Adicione essas informações para podermos lhe ajudar

Comment: Tente não adicionar somente a foto. Copie e cole o texto na pergunta, fica mais "legível".

Comment: @Randrade colei o texto do erro

Comment: Onde você está publicando isso? Me refiro ao servidor. Alguma hospedagem? Quais os passos que você faz para realizar o deply? Qual a versão do .NET?

Comment: @Randrade Está em um servidor da LocaWeb, Windows server 2012, fiz deploy via FTP do Visual Studio, o projeto está com framework 4.5.

Comment: A LocaWeb tem muitos problemas com isso. Olhe [essas perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=locaweb+%5Basp.net-mvc%5D), alguma pode lhe ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

O diretório "/site" deve ser uma aplicação na hospedagem. Verifique com a hospedagem como configurar esta pasta para aplicação.

Comment: Se puder dar um pouco mais de detalhes, ajuda bem mais o autor da pergunta e os visitantes futuros, e ainda por cima atrai +1. Anyway, bem vindo ao [pt.so] :)